# Как сохранить маркер на Yandex MapKit 3?

Tags: android, yandexmapkit

Устанавливаю маркер на карту Yandex MapKit 3. Подскажите, как его сохранить на карте, даже после того как вышел из приложения.

Answer (score 2):

Сам мапкит не сохранит маркер.

Храните данные о маркере в некой модели вашего приложения, которая переживёт перезапуск. И при старте добавляйте маркеры из модели заново.

Answer (score 0):

В SharedPreferences можно сохранить координаты, и при следующим включении метод будет подгружать их.